# Is it possible to copy text from image?

Tags: video, copy-paste, image-editing

Is there any tools to copy text from video's or images?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the image to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com) and it will use [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) to get the text from it. Or you can use a specialized software like [Abby Fine reader](http://finereader.abbyy.com/) for more advanced work.

The quality of the text recognition will vary with image quality. I would use a screenshot to get texts from video.

In **Google Drive**, you need to set Upload settings below the cogwheel on the right top to „Convert text from uploaded PDF and images files“. [image: Upload settings in Google Drive] He will copy the recognized text in the document below the image.

Answer (score 1):

I often also want to quickly copy text from images and videos. However I wasn't able to find a good solution on OS X, as procedures like uploading to Google Drive are far too cumbersome.

This is why I developed [Aristocrat](http://joshparnham.com/projects/aristocrat/), a simple app that performs OCR on a selected region of your screen. It's currently [free on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/aristocrat/id886910172?ls=1&mt=12).

Comment: I tried. Is very nice, but it seems that it can not recognize numbers. Is this the case?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Optical Character Recognition (OCR) for the job